# how to add a time wait between commands in a crontab

Tags: sleep, cron

I have a crontab where I issue two commands, and I would like to add a time sleep in between the two commands like so: (command1 ; sleep ; command2).

Is this possible? How is it formatted?

Help please!!

Answer (score 0):

The  ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
       run.  The entire command portion of the line, up  to  a  newline  or  %
       character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the
       SHELL variable of the crontab file.
- the crontab(5) man page

Essentially you already have the right base form, like:  cmd1 ; sleep 60 ; cmd2
Any command, even complicated commands with loops and other logic should work, although you should be careful about which environment variables you might be relying on.

It's useful to run job in the near future to email the output of "env" to yourself just to check ;-)

For more complex stuff, create a shell script and have the crontab refer to it, like:

42     0       *       *       *       $HOME/bin/daemon/cron-tmp-preen

Answer (score 0):

Any succession of valid `shell` commands will do. Keep all on on one line.